# How to embed an image within a ggplot figure and control the margins?

Tags: r, image, ggplot2, data-visualization

Assume we have collected data for some process where observations in our data frame occur at consecutive distances along an object. I will simulate this with `data` below:

```
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(distance = 1:1000, var1 = rnorm (1000, mean = 2, sd = 0.1))
```

We can use `ggplot` to make the following plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data, aes(x=distance, y = var1))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  ylim(c(1, 10))
```

[image]

We also have a picture of this object from which the data was collected. I made this random image in PowerPoint that we will assume is the object:

[image]

I saved this image as a .jpg to my local desktop and named it Example.jpg

Assume that the two red dots in this image represent the locations at which measurements started and ended (i.e., `distance == 1` and `distance == 1000`). We want to insert this image into the figure we created above the data, and we want to line those two points up with the first and last observations in the plot. Is there an intuitive way to achieve this?